# Event tracking for outbound links in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am attempting to set up event tags for a specific link to a specific domain that occurs several times through out my site.  I utilized Universal Analytics and the Link Click Listener and the gtm.linkClick where URL equals off domain site.com.

I am still seeing no activity on the link after having followed Google's set up docs verbatim.  Is there a way to create an Event track for outbound links within Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a tag that looks like this:

[image]

- {{gtm.elementUrl}} is a auto-event variable with variable type Element URL

Your rule should look something like this:

[image]

Questions for you:

- Are you sure you published it?
- What happens when you [inspect](http://www.swellpath.com/2013/10/google-tag-manager-inspecting-andconfiguring-auto-event-tracking/) the click of the off-site link? Do you see a new object created in the dataLayer?

Any additional context you can provide around your configuration would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup Google Analytics in GTM? 
Hard to know what is wrong without more details. Try analyzing using fiddler.